# Checking a cell in a spreadsheet for blank values

Tags: excel, powershell, if-statement

I'm trying to have powershell see if there is data in a certain cell, as no action is needed if it is blank.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('MySheet.xlsx')

$workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$WorkSheet.Name

$column = 1
$row = 2
$info = $workSheet.cells.Item($row, $column).text
#$excel.Quit()

echo $info
```

$info of course has nothing in it.

Basically, if cell A2 is blank, I'm going to exit, otherwise I'll send an email, etc.  I guess I'm asking do I convert $info to string?

I've tried

```
If($info = "")
```

and

```
If($info -eq null)
```

but I guess I'm stuck on where to go now.  How do I tell the computer "Hey, if there is anything in cell A2, do this"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks, Theo!  I have done so!  Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.text` retrieves the value of the cell as **string**. If that is not what you want, use `.Value2` to get the underlying value of the cell (can be a string, a double, etc).

To fix what you have tried with `If($info = "")`:

`=` is an assignment, not a comparison operator, so in this case you would be better off using `-eq` or even better `If([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($info))`

Also, remember that you need to remove the used COM objects from memory when done, otherwise eventually these will gobble up your computers memory.

Your code rewritten in full:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false 
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\MySheet.xlsx")
$workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)

$column = 1
$row = 3

$info = $workSheet.Cells.Item($row, $column).Text
if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($info)) {
    # cell was not empty, so do what you need to do with $info
    write-host $info
}

# we're done, so quit Excel and clean-up the COM objects used
$workbook.Close()
$excel.Quit()

# cleanup COM objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workSheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Theo!

Answer (score 0):

I went down this road before, and I highly recommend using the [ImportExcel module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel).
It makes everything much easier.